# How to use caret / timeslice for panel data?

Tags: r, panel, caret

I have panel data on stock returns and the according features. I want to do a cross-validation, using time slices.

Unfortunately, the code seem to work only for true time series.

```
timeSlices <- createTimeSlices(1:length(unique(data$ID)), 
               initialWindow = 48, horizon = 12, fixedWindow = T, skip = 11)
```

my data is in the format: ID 1, years 2000-2020; ID 2; years 2000-2020.

I want to obtain:

```
train_1: data from 2007 to 2010 // test_1 data from 2011
train_2: data from 2007 to 2011 // test_2 data from 2012
```

how can I tell caret to use panel data format? is there a way to? Is it not possible to use timeslice here?

Answer (score 0):

If the ordering of the dependent variable, the stock returns, is not important, you should then just resort to regular data splitting using `createDataPartition`, explained here: https://topepo.github.io/caret/data-splitting.html.

However, please note that stock returns are indeed time dependent and cross-validation is something that you should try to avoid when trying to forecast returns. You most likely want to keep the temporal order of the data. Hence, what is often used (in asset pricing literature) is rolling validation. `createTimeSlices` does that for you. However, from what I've seen, this supposedly only works for balanced time-series data and not for unbalanced panel data.

Comment: Thank you for you valuable comment. createTimeSlices is indeed the function I am trying to use. However, it does not work yet, as it takes every observation of every stock as a single time-point.

I miss the step where I tell the function to group all n observations of lets say 31.05.2007